# Массив обьектов

Tags: javascript

У нас есть массив обьектов data!
Для поля name надо: изменить реестр на маленький и чтоб первая буква была большой!
Для поля url надо: в начало добавить «http://» .
В итоге получаю ошибку `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name` .Если ставлю названия для функции то в итоге нечего не происходит!

```js
//Массив обьектов
var data = [{ 
 url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40069.jpg",
 name: "CHEVROLET",
 id : 1,
 params: {
  status: true,
  progress: "80"
 },
 description : "Be conveyed to users of assistive technologies – such as",
 date : 1422153200637
},{
 url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40068.jpg",
 name: "DEWOO",
 id : 2,
 params: {
  status: true,
  progress: "88"
 },
 description : "sing color to add meaning to a button",
 date : 1421153200637
},{
 url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40067.jpg",
 name: "FOLKSWAGEN",
 id : 3,
 params: {
  status: false,
  progress: "64"
 },
 description : "be conveyed to users of assistive technologies",
 date : 1426153200637
}]

var newDateUpp = data.map(function(iteam,index){
    name : function (name){return iteam.name[0] + iteam.name.slice(1).toLowerCase()}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо изменить существующие объекты или создать новые?

```js
//Массив обьектов
var data = [{
  url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40069.jpg",
  name: "CHEVROLET",
  id: 1,
  params: {
    status: true,
    progress: "80"
  },
  description: "Be conveyed to users of assistive technologies – such as",
  date: 1422153200637
}, {
  url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40068.jpg",
  name: "DEWOO",
  id: 2,
  params: {
    status: true,
    progress: "88"
  },
  description: "sing color to add meaning to a button",
  date: 1421153200637
}, {
  url: "desktopwallpapers.org.ua/mini/201507/40067.jpg",
  name: "FOLKSWAGEN",
  id: 3,
  params: {
    status: false,
    progress: "64"
  },
  description: "be conveyed to users of assistive technologies",
  date: 1426153200637
}]

// создание нового массива с новыми объектами:
var newDateUpp = data.map(function(iteam, index) {
  return {
    name: iteam.name[0] + iteam.name.slice(1).toLowerCase(),
    url: "http://" + iteam.url
  };
});
console.log(newDateUpp);

// изменение свойств существующих объектов:
data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.name = item.name[0] + item.name.slice(1).toLowerCase(),
  item.url = "http://" + item.url;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Существующие объекты, таким способом мы изменим созданые!

Comment: @DarkAdmiral не понял, попробуйте перефразировать

Comment: Если использовать map , я не смогу изменить старый обьект , но на выходе получу новый массив с уже новыми обьектами !А если буду исп. forEach , то смогу старый изменить .Верно?

Comment: @DarkAdmiral Да, я добавил оба варианта.

Comment: Спасибо больше, такой ищо вопрос если я в name захочу передать функцию в итоге я получу саму же функцию а не результат!Как получить результат?

Comment: @DarkAdmiral попробуйте показать на самом простом примере, что Вы имеете в виду

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80664/discussion-between-darkadmiral-and-igor).

Comment: Окей у нас есть data как в примере. В свойство date хочу передать функцию. 
date: function(){} 
В итоге я получу date: function().А не допустим результат date: 25.07.18